# Как законектить между собой две плата nodeMCU с esp8266 по Wi-Fi c передачей, например импульса?

Tags: wifi, lua, esp8266

У меня есть две платы nodeMCU со встроенными esp8266. Как мне связать их между собой по беспроводной связи и обмениваться данными без привязки Web-сервера, то есть подача сигнала идет с кнопки. К сожалению примера кода нет, даже ничего не написал, так как первый раз работаю с lua.

Answer (score 1):

esp8266 может работать в режиме WiFi точки (т.е. отдельный WiFi роутер по сути не обязателен, если не нужно подключение к интернету, а только общение между платами). Нужно одну из плат перевести в режим точки, задать пароль, второй платой к этой точке подключиться. Передавать данные можно просто через сокеты. Остальное зависит от конкретной задачи.

Answer (score -2):

Понадобится также WiFi-роутер, чтобы объединить их в IP-сеть.

Одна плата будет сервером, вторая - клиентом.

Обеим платам, нужно присвоить IP-адреса.

Та плата, которая будет сервером, ей нужно присвоить фиксированный адрес, чтобы плата клиент могла делать вызовы к ней по протоколу TCP.

Comment: Роутер не нужен - ESP сама может быть точкой доступа. 
Более того, в документации заявлены режимы mesh и wi-fi direct.